# Tensorflow every iteration of for loop gets slower and slower

Tags: tensorflow

I'm doing some evaluation for my algorithm where I'm comparing some generated images to a ground truth image by computing 3 different types of loss between the two images. The logic of the code is:

1. I loop over all ground truth images
2. For each ground truth image, I loop over the relevant generated images and check each against the ground truth image by computing 3 losses

The running time of the code is increasing for each iteration as seen below. This makes it so the code can't finish running in a reasonable amount of time. What could be causing this?

Code is included below. Also I'm using the Edward library for Tensorflow, if that's relevant. I create my session using the following command:

```
sess = ed.get_session()
```

Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [01:36<00:00,  2.53s/it]
---------- Summary Image 001 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [01:44<00:00,  2.61s/it]
---------- Summary Image 002 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [01:57<00:00,  3.59s/it]
---------- Summary Image 003 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [02:16<00:00,  3.34s/it]
---------- Summary Image 004 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [02:25<00:00,  3.56s/it]
---------- Summary Image 005 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [02:45<00:00,  4.00s/it]
---------- Summary Image 006 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [02:54<00:00,  4.19s/it]
---------- Summary Image 007 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [03:11<00:00,  4.58s/it]
---------- Summary Image 008 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [03:26<00:00,  5.02s/it]
---------- Summary Image 009 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [03:38<00:00,  5.58s/it]
---------- Summary Image 010 ------------
Starting evaluation...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 40/40 [03:51<00:00,  5.77s/it]

```
for i in range(inference_batch_size):
    compare_vae_hmc_loss(model.decode_op, model.encode_op, model.discriminator_l_op,
                               x_ad[i:i+1], samples_to_check[:, i, :], config)

def compare_vae_hmc_loss(P, Q, DiscL, x_gt, samples_to_check, config):
    print ("Starting evaluation...")

    x_samples_to_check = ...

    for i, sample in enumerate(tqdm(x_samples_to_check)):

        for j in range(sample_to_vis):
            plot_save(x_samples_to_check[j], './out/{}_mcmc_sample_{}.png'.format(img_num, j + 1))

        avg_img = np.mean(x_samples_to_check, axis=0)
        plot_save(avg_img, './out/{}_mcmcMean.png'.format(img_num))

        r_loss = recon_loss(x_gt, sample)
        l_loss = l2_loss(x_gt, sample)
        lat_loss = l_latent_loss(l_th_x_gt, l_th_layer_samples[i:i+1])
        total_recon_loss += r_loss
        total_l2_loss += l_loss
        total_latent_loss += lat_loss

        if r_loss < best_recon_loss:
            best_recon_sample = sample
            best_recon_loss = r_loss

        if l_loss < best_l2_loss:
            best_l2_sample = sample
            best_l2_loss = l_loss

        if lat_loss < best_latent_loss:
            best_latent_sample = sample
            best_latent_loss = lat_loss

def l2_loss(x_gt, x_hmc):
    if jernej_Q_P:
        return tf.norm(x_gt - x_hmc).eval()
    else:
        return tf.norm(x_gt-x_hmc).eval()


def recon_loss(x_gt, x_hmc):
    if jernej_Q_P:
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_hmc, labels=x_gt), 1).eval()
    else:
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_hmc[1], labels=x_gt), 1).eval()


def l_latent_loss(l_th_x_gt, l_th_x_hmc):
    return tf.norm(l_th_x_gt - l_th_x_hmc).eval()
```

Comment: There's missing code here so I'm not quite sure what to say, but usually when you're slowing down each iteration, it's because you're accidentally adding to / recreating the graph instead of defining the graph *once* and then executing it multiple times.  For example, here you're calling compare_vae... once per batch size, which is adding tf ops to a graph.

That may be enough of a hint to solve your problem, but if not, can you include the code that creates the session and more importantly, the code that calls eval or run?

Comment: Hm I think I'm only calling run/eval when I compute the 3 different losses, so I'm not sure what else to include. Anyway, here is a gist with minimal lines removed from my code https://gist.github.com/shenkev/f8f4d2f2f05d6fc81e20b2e49a35c2ba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding new ops to the graph every sample you process -- the `compare_vae_hmc_loss` function adds new nodes (it calls tf. functions) every time it's executed.  This means that your graph is getting bigger and bigger and taking more and more memory.

What you need to do is define the computational graph *once* and then invoke it multiple times.  All of those calls like `return tf.norm(x_gt-x_hmc).eval()` are *creating a new node* in the graph that will persist forever.  Instead, you should save the nodes you create once, remember the python variable, and then pull on that node each time you need it.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the problem. I was able to fix it by replacing all the for-loops with tensor computations (I guess the way Tensorflow was meant to be used!) so the computation graph isn't growing and growing.